# get first value of a field based on the max of another field while other max fields are also being used

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm using multiple MAX statements to get the "last activity" for students.  Students have an enrollment record for each year they enroll.  I get all the correct results with the exception of one field..***the school name of the last school the student was enrolled at.***  The last school can be found by getting the school name from the record that holds the last entry date...but I can't seem to find a solution, or haven't put the code in the correct place..or something.   The different ways I've tried are indented comments at the bottom.
    DECLARE @grade char(2);
    Set @grade='00'

```
Select 
SD.[Last_Name],
SD.[First_Name],
SD.[Middle_Name],
SD.[Name_Appendage] as [Name_Suffix],
convert(varchar,cast(SD.[DOB] as date),101) as [Date_Of_Birth],
SD.[Student_Number] as [Student_Number],
Max (SE.[Academic_Year]) as [Academic_Year],
Max (CONVERT(VARCHAR, SE.[Withdrawal_Date], 101)) as 
[Last_Withdrawal_Date],
Max (CONVERT(VARCHAR, SE.[Graduation_Date], 101)) as 
[Graduation_Date],
Max (SD.[DOE_Number]) as [State_Id],
Max (CONVERT(VARCHAR, SE.[Entry_Date], 101)) as [Last_Entry_Date],
Max (SE.[Graduation_Year]) as [Graduation_Year],
Max (CASE when SE.[Grade_Level] > '12' then @grade 
else SE.[Grade_Level]
End) as [Grade_Level]
From
Student_DemographicsCube as SD WITH (NOLOCK),
Student_EnrollmentCube as SE WITH (NOLOCK)
Where
SD.[Student_ID] = SE.[Student_ID] And
SE.[Entry_Date] > cast('12/31/2001' as date) And
SE.[School_Domain] in 
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,26,27,28,29,30,31)
Group By
SD.[Student_Number],
SD.[First_Name],
SD.[Middle_Name],
SD.[Last_Name],
SD.[Name_Appendage],
SD.[DOB]
Order By
SD.[Student_Number] asc,
Max (SE.[Entry_Date]) asc
```

Attempted Solutions to last enrolled at school name

```
/* Select TOP (1) (SE.[School_Name]) from */
/*                Student_EnrollmentCube order by (SE.[Entry_Date) desc ) */
/* (Select SE.[School_Name] from Student_EnrollmentCube as */
/*        ST with (NOLOCK) where @holddate = SE.[Entry_Date]) */
/*SE.[School_Name] as [School_Name] */
/* Max (CASE when Max (SE.[Entry_Date]) = SE.[Entry_Date] */
/*                  then SE.[School_Name] */
/*                else @school */ 
/*            End) as [School_Name] */
/*      Select TOP (1) SE.[School_Name] from */
/*               Student_EnrollmentCube Group by SE.[Student_Number] */
/*                      order by SE.[Entry_Date] desc  */
/*ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SE. */
/*           [Student_NUmber],SE.[Academic_Year] ORDER BY SD.*/
/*       [Student_Number],SE.[Academic_Year]) as seqnum */
/*               FROM SE.[Academic_Year] t */
/*             ) t */
/*           WHERE seqnum = 1; */ 


/*6/2/17 Code____________________________________________/*
DECLARE @grade char(2);
Set @grade='00'
Select 
SD.[Last_Name],
SD.[First_Name],
SD.[Middle_Name],
SD.[Name_Appendage] as [Name_Suffix],
    convert(varchar,cast(SD.[DOB] as date),101) as [Date_Of_Birth],
SD.[Student_Number] as [Student_Number],
     Max (SE.[Academic_Year]) as [Academic_Year],
convert(varchar,cast(w.[Last_Withdrawal_date] as date),101) as 
     [Latest_Withdrawal_Date] ,
convert(varchar,cast(g.[Last_Graduation_Date] as date),101) as 
     [Latest_Graduation_Date] ,
Max (SD.[DOE_Number]) as [State_Id],
Max (CONVERT(VARCHAR, e.[Entry_Date], 101)) as [Last_Entry_Date],
Max (SE.[Graduation_Year]) as [Graduation_Year],
Max (CASE when SE.[Grade_Level] > '12' then @grade 
     else SE.[Grade_Level]
     End) as [Grade_Level],
e.[School_Name]
From
Student_DemographicsCube SD WITH (NOLOCK),
Student_EnrollmentCube SE WITH (NOLOCK)
cross apply (select top 1 e.[School_Name], e.[Entry_Date] from 
    Student_EnrollmentCube e
    where e.[Student_id] = se.[Student_id] and se.[entry_date] > 
    cast('12/31/2001' as date) order by  e.[Student_ID], e.[Entry_Date] 
    desc) i
cross apply (select top 1 w.[Withdrawal_Date] as [Last_Withdrawal_Date] 
    from Student_EnrollmentCube w
    where w.[Student_id] = se.[Student_id] and se.[entry_date] > 
    cast('12/31/2001' as date) order by w.[Student_id], w.[Withdrawal_Date] 
    desc) w
cross apply (select top 1 g.[Graduation_Date] as [Last_Graduation_Date] 
    from Student_EnrollmentCube g
    where g.[Student_id] = se.[Student_id] and se.[entry_date] > 
    cast('12/31/2001' as date) order by g.[Student_id], g.[Graduation_Date] 
    desc) g

Where
SD.[Student_ID] = SE.[Student_ID] And sd.[student_Number] = 700010068 and
     SE.[Entry_Date] > cast('12/31/2001' as date) And
SE.[School_Domain] in 
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,13,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)

Group By
SD.[Student_Number],
SD.[First_Name],
SD.[Middle_Name],
SD.[Last_Name],
SD.[Name_Appendage],
SD.[DOB],
e.[school_name],
w.[Last_Withdrawal_Date],
g.[Last_Graduation_Date]

Order By
SD.[Student_Number] asc,
Max (SE.[Entry_Date]) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the latest row from `Student_EnrollmentCube` for the latest entry date and school name

```
declare @grade char(2);
set @grade = '00';

select
    sd.Last_Name
  , sd.First_Name
  , sd.Middle_Name
  , Name_Suffix            = sd.Name_Appendage
  , Date_Of_Birth          = convert(char(10), convert(date,sd.dob), 101)
  , Student_Number         = sd.Student_Number
  , Academic_Year          = max(se.Academic_Year)
  , Latest_Withdrawal_Date = convert(char(10), max(convert(date,se.Withdrawal_date)), 101)
  , Latest_Graduation_Date = convert(char(10), max(convert(date,se.Graduation_Date)), 101)
  , State_Id               = max(sd.doe_Number)
  , x.Last_Entry_Date        
  , x.School_Name            
  , Graduation_Year        = max(se.Graduation_Year)
  , Grade_Level            = case when max(try_convert(int,se.Grade_Level)) > 12 then @grade else se.Grade_Level end)
from Student_DemographicsCube sd
  inner join Student_EnrollmentCube se
    on sd.Student_id = se.Student_id
  cross apply (
     select top 1 
          i.School_Name
        , Last_Entry_Date = i.Entry_Date
     from Student_EnrollmentCube i
     where i.Student_id = si.Student_id
     order by convert(date,i.Entry_Date) desc
    ) x
where sd.student_Number = 700010068
  and se.Entry_Date > convert(date,'20011231')
  and se.School_Domain in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,13,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)
group by 
    sd.Student_Number
  , sd.First_Name
  , sd.Middle_Name
  , sd.Last_Name
  , sd.Name_Appendage
  , sd.dob
  , x.Last_Entry_Date
  , x.School_Name
order by 
    sd.Student_Number asc
  , x.Last_Entry_Date asc
```

Notes / Reference:

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)
- [Bad habits to kick : declaring `varchar` without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)
- [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- The only truly safe formats for date/time literals in SQL Server, at least for `datetime` and `smalldatetime` are: `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]`

Comment: I do need max on the fields indicated max...but I only need most recent on school name.  Do I take my original code and add the cross apply code to the end of it?

Comment: I took my original code..added the cross apply after the FROM statement.  The code ran, without errors, but I did not get school name to appear in the output.

Comment: I am not getting school name in the output.  If I try to move the cross apply at the end of my original code I get the error incorrect syntax near the word "cross" and incorrect syntax near the word "order", so I assume the cross apply has to be after the FROM statement....it will run if it is there, but no school name is in the output.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @BillG Are you saying `School_Name` is `null`?

Comment: No, the column does not appear in the output.

Comment: @BillG ... You have to add the column to the `select` list...  If you look at the query in my answer, you will find `, x.School_Name` in the `select` list. along with `, (convert(varchar(30), x.Entry_Date, 101)) as Last_Entry_Date`. My mistake was `x` was not set as the alias for the `cross apply()` in this version of the query, I have corrected it.

Comment: Finally got the correct School name in the output, but now the max entry date is not correct.  Why would the max entry date change?

Comment: @BillG Shouldn't be using `max()` on the `Entry_Date`. Just `group by x.Entry_Date` and use `(convert(varchar(30), x.Entry_Date, 101)) as Last_Entry_Date`

Comment: I don't think that will work because there are many entry dates from the enrollment records...I only want the latest entry date..and the latest withdrawal...and the latest graduation...and the latest school name.  I have modified the code and now have "stacked" joins.  During testing it was discovered that inconsistent results were being given. Like- The latest withdrawal date is correct for some...not for all..some who should have a withdrawal date showed up with none.  Still working on it.

Comment: @BillG The `cross apply()` already returns the latest row for each `student_id`. That is what the `select top 1 ... order by i.Entry_Date desc` is doing. If you post some example data, I can show you a demo.

Comment: I understand it gets the latest row for each student_id and the corresponding latest entry date...but the latest withdrawal date (and other dates) are in different records.  I have tried putting a second cross apply sorting on student and withdrawal date to get the most recent withdrawal date...but it doesn't work for all students.

Comment: I added todays "version" of the code so you could see the multiple cross applys.  Are they coded properly?

Comment: @BillG Almost, but the aliases and references are mixed up and the filters are misplaced and extra stuff was added to the order etc. but I updated my answer, that might be what you need.